# CMSMS Formbuilder Multi Page Form Not uploading Files

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data, formbuilder, cmsmadesimple

I have created a multi page form using the formbuilder module for CMS Made Simple.

The form is submitting all other fields correctly however the upload file inputs are not uploading to the uploads directory.

I have created other forms that work perfectly using the exact same settings so it seems there is a bug in formbuilder itself for multi page forms however I am unable to figure out what it is to be able to fix it.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the files are not being uploaded.

Once this is fixed it will also be attached to the email that is sent as the form is submitted but this is an easy fix (just un ticking the box).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a bug in the formbuilder module itself. A request was made on the CMSMS forge but no replies have been received.

Unfortunately there is no fix so depending on the version of formbuilder you are using you will not be able to upload files if you have a multi page form.